# Checking if XOR is also true for statements, in addition with OR in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-construction, xor, bitwise-xor

Currently, i have the following function which returns of a bool if the element is a start of declaration or start of statement.

```
bool start_of_block_element() {
     return start_of_declaration() || start_of_statement();
```

I need to check if XOR of these is also true and output a bool. I am not sure how to combine them together. It should return true if both XOR and OR returns true

My guess is:

```
bool start_of_block_element() {
    return ( 

      (start_of_declaration() ^ start_of_statement() ) && ( start_of_declaration() || start_of_statement() )

    );
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Depends on what the functions return and what you are supposed to return.  Do you only return true if the xor is true or does the xor need to be true and on or the other needs to be true?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It should return true if both xor and or returns true.

Comment: Put that in the question. Are the two other functions bool? I have a better way in mind.

Comment: yes, the other functions are bool. please feel free to share

Comment: For bools a and b, this is the equivalent XOR operation:  `a != b`.

Comment: If `x XOR y` is true, `x OR y` is necessarily true so the extra test is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `bool D = start_of_declaration()` and `bool S = start_of_statement()`

You want `D || S == true`, and `D ^ S == true`. So basically,

> D | S | return
>   --+---+----
>   0 | 0 | 0
>   1 | 0 | 1
>   0 | 1 | 1
>   1 | 1 | 0

Any operator which gives this truth table will satisfy your requirements, so use the operator which has this truth table:

```
return start_of_declaration() != start_of_statement()
```

Comment: what if i wanted it to pass if and only if both bools return the same result?

Comment: Most people write that "==" in c++. (but it's not what you asked for) Either way, document why, because I would think it weird if I were reading that code. It's not the start of a block because it's the start of something else too? Why?

Comment: @Utsab That goes against what you want.  If both variables are the same when you xor them together it'll be false

Comment: What do you think the truth table of `^` is?

Comment: Which points to the fact that the `||` computation is strictly redundant.